# How to make update data of mysql in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, routes, updates

I'm trying to make an update with values from a form and pass it into an update controller using a route, there's no error given but why there's nothing happen after I updated the data?

Form:

```
<form action="/update" id="frm_edit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/update', 'EditManga@update'); //update route
Route::post('/admin_page/manga_list', 'Add_Manga_Controller@upload')->name('upload.image');
Route::get('/admin_page/manga_list','ShowData@Manga_list');
```

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg'
        ]);

        //MENGAMBIL FILE IMAGE DARI FORM
        $kode_manga = $request->input('kdmanga');
        $judul = $request->input('jdmanga');
        $alternatif = $request->input('almanga');
        $author = $request->input('aumanga');
        $status = $request->status;
        $lastup = $request->input('lumanga');
        $genre = $request->input('grmanga');
        $lastc = $request->input('lcmanga');
        $sinopsis = $request->input('sinopsis');
        $file = $request->file('image');

        DB::table('add_manga')->where('kode_manga',$kode_manga)->update([
            'judul_manga' => $judul,
            'alt_title' => $alternatif,
            'author' => $author,
            'status' => $status,
            'uploaded' => $lastup,
            'genre' => $genre,
            'latest' => $lastc,
            'summary' => $sinopsis
        ]);
        return redirect('/admin_page/manga_list');
    }
}
```

is there any other way or there something's wrong with my code?, Thank you.

Comment: could you show us the table in your mysql

Comment: sure, https://i.imgur.com/iNolCal.png

Comment: and one more thing do you have you used modal for your table

Comment: yes I am using it

Comment: show me the modal name of this table

Comment: I'm using javascript to pass the values from a table to a modal by using a button click https://i.imgur.com/8MdUdY0.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you scenario this another of doing this:

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
  {


    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg'
    ]);

    //MENGAMBIL FILE IMAGE DARI FORM
    $kode_manga = $request->input('kdmanga');

    //getting the target row to updae
    $addmanga = DB::table('add_manga')->select('*')
            ->where('kode_manga',$kode_manga)->get();

    $id = $addmanga->id; // getting the id of the target

    $add_manga = App\YOUR_MODEL_NAME::find($id);

    $add_manga->judul_manga = $request->input('jdmanga');
    $add_manga->alt_title = $request->input('almanga');
    $add_manga->author = $request->input('aumanga');
    $add_manga->status = $request->status;
    $add_manga->uploaded = $request->input('lumanga');
    $add_manga->genre = $request->input('grmanga');
    $add_manga->latest = $request->input('lcmanga');
    $add_manga->summary = $request->input('sinopsis');
    $add_manga->file = $request->file('image');

    $add_manga->save();

    return redirect('/admin_page/manga_list');
}
```

Hope this will work for you!